# MS Dynamics NAV XML Namespace is set automatically

Tags: xml, dom, dynamics-nav

I'm creating a new XML File out of a table. The problem is I don't want the children of the root node to have the attribute xmlns. This happens automatically and its incorrect. If i have the attribute on the root element, no matter how it gets there it puts it in its child-nodes. How can I get rid of it?

A

Locals
Name DataType Subtype Length

```
L_DataXML Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.DOMDocument60 
L_XMLElement Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMElement 
L_XMLAttribute Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMAttribute 
L_XMLNode Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMNode 
L_XMLOrderHeader Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMNode 
L_XMLOrderItemList Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMNode 
L_XMLOrderSummary Automation 'Microsoft XML, v6.0'.IXMLDOMNode
```

C/AL CODE

```
L_DataXML.loadXML('<ORDER xmlns="test"/>');

L_XMLNode := L_DataXML.documentElement;

L_XMLOrderHeader := L_DataXML.createNode(1,'ORDER_HEADER','');
L_XMLNode.appendChild(L_XMLOrderHeader);
```

XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ORDER xmlns="test">
    <ORDER_HEADER xmlns=""/>
</ORDER>
```

Comment: Note that [Microsoft has a Knowledge Base article on this exact problem](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/828928).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem too a while ago. Unforunatley, there is no way you can prevent that using XMLDOM. My workaround was to create the XML File with the error, load it into a bigtext variable and loop through it while erasing xmlns=""

Code:

```
XMLFile.TEXTMODE(FALSE);
XMLFile.OPEN(SavePath);
XMLFile.CREATEINSTREAM(InStream);
InputText.READ(InStream);
XMLFile.CLOSE;

TextToFind := 'xmlns=""';
TextPos := InputText.TEXTPOS(TextToFind);
WHILE TextPos <> 0 DO BEGIN
  InputText.GETSUBTEXT(SubText, 1, TextPos - 1);
  OutputText.ADDTEXT(SubText);
  InputText.GETSUBTEXT(InputText, TextPos + STRLEN(TextToFind));
  TextPos := InputText.TEXTPOS(TextToFind);
END;
OutputText.ADDTEXT(InputText);

XMLFile.TEXTMODE(FALSE);
XMLFile.CREATE(SavePath);
XMLFile.CREATEOUTSTREAM(OutStream);
OutputText.WRITE(OutStream);
XMLFile.CLOSE;
```

Variables

```
Name    DataType    Subtype Length
XMLFile File        
InStream    InStream        
OutStream   OutStream       
InputText   BigText     
OutputText  BigText     
SubText BigText     
TextPos Integer     
TextToFind  Text        30
SavePath    Text        1024
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answer. Thats true there is no way of getting ridd of it! But i found a workaround to allow at least the valiadion of the file. Adding the default namespace from the root allows the document to be valid.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ORDER xmlns="test">
    <ORDER_HEADER xmlns="test"/>
</ORDER>
```

another issue which someone else might come across was a second namespace

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ORDER xmlns="test" xmlns:second="second-test">
    <ORDER_HEADER xmlns="test">
          <second:TAG/>
    </ORDER_HEADER>
</ORDER>
```

at first it results to an error because it doesnt find the second namespace. Just add the namespace URI to the AddFunciton and it wont complain anymore.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

when use createNode method use namespaceURI from parent node.
probably should work if you would change to
L_XMLOrderHeader := L_DataXML.createNode(1,'ORDER_HEADER',L_DataXML.namespaceURI);